# How to disable preselected value checkbox in React Multiselect dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

In there I used disablePreSelectedValues property to disable value selected. but in the dropdown it shows all the option and also it's enable to unchecked. Any idea how to disable checkbox?

[image]

```
<Multiselect
     options={this.state.options} // Options to display in the dropdown
     selectedValues={this.state.selectedValue} // Preselected value to persist in dropdown
     onSelect={this.onSelect} // Function will trigger on select event
     onRemove={this.onRemove} // Function will trigger on remove event
     displayValue="name" // Property name to display in the dropdown options
     showCheckbox={true}
     disablePreSelectedValues={this.state.disablePreSelectedValues} />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code here :

https://github.com/srigar/multiselect-react-dropdown/blob/89d7ca40b2631c28849d4ceec9bbb3326cc478f2/src/multiselect/multiselect.component.js#L370

```
isDisablePreSelectedValues(value) {
    const { isObject, disablePreSelectedValues, displayValue } = this.props;
    const { preSelectedValues } = this.state;
    if (!disablePreSelectedValues || !preSelectedValues.length) {
      return false;
    }
    if (isObject) {
      return (
        preSelectedValues.filter(i => i[displayValue] === value[displayValue])
          .length > 0
      );
    }
    return preSelectedValues.filter(i => i === value).length > 0;
  }
```

You also need to pass preSelectedValues array, if you want them to be disabled.Try something like this:

```
<Multiselect
     options={this.state.options} // Options to display in the dropdown
     selectedValues={this.state.selectedValue} // Preselected value to persist in dropdown
     onSelect={this.onSelect} // Function will trigger on select event
     onRemove={this.onRemove} // Function will trigger on remove event
     displayValue="name" // Property name to display in the dropdown options
     showCheckbox={true}
     disablePreSelectedValues={this.state.disablePreSelectedValues} 
     preSelectedValues={selectedValues}
/>
```